# Remove elements from a big dict, in place

Tags: python, dictionary, in-place

I have a dict that has millions of elements, and can use hundreds of megabytes of memory.
I want to remove certain elements, based on a condition on the key:

```
d = {k: k for k in range(10_000_000)}        # simplified example

def mycondition(x):             
    return x % 10 != 0                       # simplified
```

- This will work, but it will do a new copy of the dict, so I'd like to avoid it:

  ```
  d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if mycondition(k)}
  ```

  because it would use the double of the RAM than needed compared to an "in place" solution
- This fails:

  ```
  for k, v in d.items():
      if not mycondition(k):
          del d[k]
  ```

  because

  > RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

**How to solve this problem "in place", i.e. without using twice the size of `d` in RAM?**

Comment: You need to work on a copy of the items: `for k, v in list(d.items()):`

Comment: `list(d.items())` makes a copy, so it doubles the RAM usage @LaurentLAPORTE.

Comment: The dict comprehension approach doesn't need double the RAM - yes, you have two dicts in memory at the same time, but they are sharing the same key and value objects.

Comment: Isn't there any way to access the elements of lists in reverse order. If there is then the problem can be solved easily.

Comment: May I ask how do you obtain such dictionary? Perhaps a solution is just to filter out the keys at construction time.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I first wanted to answer "impossible", but finally, maybe :)... I'll rethink about the whole construction process and I'll see if this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

I may have a simple solution - not a in place solution but it does not take double of the space.

```
d = {k: k for k in range(200)}

# List that stores the keys that should be removed
ids_to_remove = []

def mycondition(x):
    return x % 10 != 0

for k in d:
    if not mycondition(k):
        ids_to_remove.append(k)

for key in ids_to_remove:
    d.pop(key)
```

Comment: no need to iterate over the items, the predicate is for the keys

Comment: @Basj yes, or `d.keys()` to make it explicit

Comment: You can also write : `ids_to_remove = {k for k in d if not mycondition(k)}` (set in comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

Dicts are iterable and iterables can be run through a filter to create another iterable. Since these are just pulling from the same source and iterating over them with **next** you shouldn't introduce any extra overhead when you finally use the iterable. Rather than modifying the dictionary in place, you can instead change the iterable and only evaluate it at the last possible moment when you absolutely have to. The best way to save on memory is if you can convert the generation of the dictionary itself into an iterable so it isn't even stored in memory before the filters. There is the OO way of making iterators but here is an more basic example:

```
d = map(lambda x: (x, x), range(10_000_000))
i = filter(lambda t: t[1] % 10 != 0, d)
i_2 = filter(lambda t: t[1] % 15 != 0, i)
# ... as many modifications as I want
output = json.dumps(dict(i_n))
```

Until we reach the output step, our iterators take up comparatively no space compared to having it all in memory. If you are loading this from a file, a similar approach could be used to iterate over each line.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for k in list(d.keys()):
    if not mycondition(k):
        d.pop(k)
```

Comment: I don't know then we have to use list() function.